In nonlinear systems with at least 1 asymptotically stable point is it true that every point on the phase plane is in a basin of attraction/separatrix
In differential equations, for a system of autonomous nonlinear differential equations, is it true that if there exists at least one asymptotically stable point, then EVERY point in the phase plane belongs to either the separatrix or basin of attraction of an asymptotically stable point?
So far, in my ODE class I've only seen examples where this is the case.
So if this is not necessarily true, could you provide some examples of a nonlinear system with at least 1 asymptotically stable point where there exists trajectories that neither lie on a separatrix or approach any asymptotically stable critical point as t-> infinity?

No, there are also limit cycles. If you add a saddle point to the picture, then the phase space can be split in regions as you describe, both doubly infinite trajectories and such converging to a stable point existing simultaneously.

@LutzLehmann for limit cycles, you're referring to "unstable" limit cycles, right?

Yes, with a stable point inside, the innermost limit cycle will be unstable. It is still a periodic solution and thus not of the two types you mentioned.

For an example of such a system, consider $\dot{x} = -x(1-x^2-y^2) - y$, $\dot{y} = -y(1-x^2-y^2)+x$. The origin is asymptotically stable, however every trajectory with $x^2+y^2 > 1$ goes off to infinity.
